# Javascript Array of Objects, with two methods and two call functions

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript. I have to build an array of five object with two methods and two call functions. With a Web Developer friend of mine, we created the following code. Yet, I do not know how to progress any further than this. Can you guys lend me a hand?

Instructions:

Create a variable named actors and assign to it an array of five objects, each
of which represents a famous actor. Each actor object should have properties for
the actor's name, the actor's age, and the number of Oscars the actor has
received (you can call this property oscars or numOscars). These are the actors
to use:

```
Leonardo DiCaprio (age 41, 1 Oscar)
Jennifer Lawrence (age 25, 1 Oscar)
Samuel L. Jackson (age 67, no Oscars)
Meryl Streep (age 66, 3 Oscars)
John Cho (age 43, no Oscars)
```

In addition to the three properties already mentioned, each actor object should
have the following two methods:

```
hello - this method logs to the console the string "Hello, my name is "
    followed by the actor's name.

hasMoreOscarsThan - this method accepts one actor object as a parameter and
    returns true if the actor has more Oscars than the one that is passed as
    a parameter and false otherwise.
```

Now write the following functions:

```
getActorByName - this function expects a string as a parameter and returns
    the object in the actors array whose name property is equal to the
    string that is passed in (if there is one).

getAverageAge - this function returns the average age of all the actors in
    the array.
```

You can run commands such as those below and verify the output.

```
var leo = getActorByName('Leonardo DiCaprio');
var jlaw = getActorByName('Jennifer Lawrence');
var jcho = getActorByName('John Cho');
var meryl = getActorByName('Meryl Streep');

jlaw.hasMoreOscarsThan(jcho);
jlaw.hasMoreOscarsThan(meryl);
leo.hasMoreOscarsThan(jlaw);

meryl.hello();
leo.hello();

getAverageAge();
```

```js
var BaseActor = function ( actor_details ) {
    this.details = actor_details
    this.hello = function () {
      console.log(this.details.name)
    }
    this.hasMoreOscarsThan = function( otherActor ) {
      return this.details.oscars > otherActor.details.oscars
    }
}

function getActorByName(name) {
  console.log(name)
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
    console.log(i, actors[i]);
    if (actors[i].name == name) {
      return actor[i]
    }
  }
  console.log('not found a shit', i)
  return false
}

var leo = new BaseActor({ id: 0, name: "Leonardo di Caprio", age: 41, oscars: 1, hello:"Hello, my name is Leonardo di Caprio"})
var jen = new BaseActor({ id: 1, name: "Jennifer Lawrence", age: 25, oscars: 1, hello:"Hello my name is Jennifer Lawrence"})
var sam = new BaseActor({ id: 2, name: "Samuel L. Jackson", age: 67, oscars: 0, hello:"Hello my name is Samuel L. Jackson"})
var meryl = new BaseActor({ id: 3, name: "Meryl Streep", age: 66, oscars: 3, hello:"Hello my name is Meryl Streep"})
var john = new BaseActor({ id: 4, name: "John Cho", age: 43, oscars: 0, hello:"Hello my name is John Cho"})

var actors = [
  leo,
  jen,
  sam,
  meryl,
  john
]

leo.hello()
console.log(leo.hasMoreOscarsThan(jen))
console.log(
  getActorByName("John Cho").id
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just went ahead and completely rewrote this problem into a completely working solution for fun. Just call the functions as you need at the bottom. I even left examples that you just need to uncomment. Have fun!

Below is the code, but here is also the repl that I used to write this... https://repl.it/repls/FeistyButteryLoop

```js
let actors = [
  
  { 
    name:'Leonardo DiCaprio',
    age: 41, 
    oscars: 1, 
    hello: function hello() {console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`)},
    hasMoreOscarsThan: function hasMoreOscarsThan(actor) {
      if (this.oscars > actor.oscars) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    name:'Jennifer Lawrence',
    age:25,
    oscars:1,
    hello:function hello() {console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`)},
    hasMoreOscarsThan:function hasMoreOscarsThan(actor) {
      if (this.oscars > actor.oscars) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    name:'Samuel L. Jackson',
    age:67,
    oscars:0,
    hello:function hello() {console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`)},
    hasMoreOscarsThan:function hasMoreOscarsThan(actor) {
      if (this.oscars > actor.oscars) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    name:'Meryl Streep',
    age:66,
    oscars:3,
    hello:function hello() {console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`)},
    hasMoreOscarsThan:function hasMoreOscarsThan(actor) {
      if (this.oscars > actor.oscars) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  },
  
  {
    name:'John Cho',
    age:43, oscars:0,
    hello:function hello() {console.log(`Hello, my name is ${this.name}`)},
    hasMoreOscarsThan:function hasMoreOscarsThan(actor) {
      if (this.oscars > actor.oscars) {
        return true
      } else {
        return false
      }
    }
  }
]
  
  const getActorByName = (name) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
      if (actors[i].name === name) {
        return actors[i]
      }
    }
  }
  
  const getAverageAge = () => {
    let totalAge = 0;
    for (let i = 0; i < actors.length; i++) {
      totalAge += actors[i].age
    }
    return `Average actors age: ${totalAge / actors.length}`
  }
  
  let leo = getActorByName('Leonardo DiCaprio');
  let jlaw = getActorByName('Jennifer Lawrence');
  let sam = getActorByName('Samuel L. Jackson');
  let meryl = getActorByName('Meryl Streep');
  let jcho = getActorByName('John Cho');
  
  //uncomment line below to call hello function on actor variables above
  //jcho.hello()
  
  //uncomment line below to call has more oscars function using actor variables above
  //leo.hasMoreOscarsThan(meryl)
  
  //uncomment line below to call getAverageAge function
  //getAverageAge()
```

Comment: Hello Michael, thanks for your help. Yet, is your code still an array of objects with values and methods. I thought an array has to be coded the way I did?

Comment: Yes it is an array of objects.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp

All an array is in JS is [ ] which is then filled with strings, numbers, objects, other arrays, etc.

A method in javascript is simply a function definition that is a property of an object. 

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_methods.asp

The solution I wrote completely satisfies the instructions in your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the array to the sum of actor ages and divide that by the length of the array.

```
function getAverageAge() {
  return actors.reduce(//reduce actors array to sum of actor ages
    function(totalAge,actor){
      return totalAge + actor.details.age;
    },
    0//initial value is 0
  ) / actors.length
}
```